# Failure booting my custom kernel

Tags: linux, debian, kernel

I compiled and installed a custom Linux kernel using Debian kernel-package. Everything went OK: .deb files were created and custom vmlinuz and initrd.img were created in /boot and /boot/grub/menu.lst were modified automatically. But after I boot into the custom kernel, here is what happens:

After some progress, writes the following:

```
Begin: Waiting for root file system
```

and waits for a while. And then prints this:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
    - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
        - Check root delay= (did the system wait long enough?)
        - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
    - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)

ALERT! doesn't exist. Dropping to a shell!

/bin/sh
(initramfs)
```

and jumps to shell in the RAM. When I tried `mount /dev/hda6 /tmp/hda6`, there really is no hda6. hda6 is the partition running my Debian and including the custom initrd.img.

Please help me guys!

Comment: Is it maybe because I have small space left in my partition? The free space left is about 600MB.

Comment: when the custom kernel drops you to a shell, you need to look in `/dev` to find the right hard drive device.  if this is a recent kernel with udev, there should be some symlinks in `/dev/disk/by-UUID` that will help identify the new device.

Answer (score 3):

This problem happens when the `root=` line in your kernel boot options doesn't match the hardware.

Probably, your new kernel isn't giving your boot device the `/dev/hda` device node.  There are a couple of possibilities.

1. It may be that your device is now `/dev/hdb` or some such.
2. It may be that your kernel is now using a newer driver for the device, and your boot device is now `/dev/sda` or some such.  `/dev/hd{a..z}` devices use the older PATA driver.  This became prevalent for SATA devices, but older PATA interfaces can be accessed this way as well.  (Ubuntu, for example, uses this by default, except for PATA optical drives.)

The easiest way to fix it is to boot the kernel, wait for it to drop you to a shell, and check `/dev/disk/by-uuid` or `/dev/disk/by-label` to figure out the correct device.  Then you can mount the device, correct the `root=` argument in your Grub configuration, and reboot.

Consider using a UUID or partition label in your `root=` argument instead of a specific device; this way kernel driver changes that rename your device won't affect boot.  You can find UUIDs and labels with `tune2fs -l <device>`, and you can add a label with `sudo tune2fs -L <label> <device>`.

Here's the `root=` argument each way (note no quotes):

```
root=/dev/sda6
root=UUID=94b1e7d5-9fc5-4f44-b5b1-c776afc808d4
root=LABEL=debian-root-volume-label
```

Comment: I did as you said. But it couldn't help.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to check is does your kernel even recognize your hardware.

- First, check the type of your hard drive and ensure that it is enabled in kernel configuration. This is most likely the cause of your problem.
- I don't remember if there is a `dmesg` program included in Debian default initramfs, but you can check your kernel debug output typing `dmesg | less`. Then try to find lines that are related to your hard drive. Also, it is useful to know vendor or at least interface of the drive.
- At last, you can remove the `quiet` boot option from kernel commandline if any and then simply scroll up debug output with Shift+PgUp/PgDn keys searching same info as in previous paragraph.

Also it will be probably a good idea to provide some information about hard drive in HD-related question.